# Method returning an unmodifiable list

Tags: java, collections

In Java you could return a list that cannot be modified by the caller by doing `return Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`.

Should the method name indicate that it's returning an unmodifiable list? That could prevent clients of my class from attempting to add or remove objects from the list.

Comment: I'm not that into java at the moment so maybe this is stupid, but in C# I would just make the method return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IList<T>`. Why not return an `Iterable` if you don't want to allow mutation?

Comment: @kai - I would certainly advocate such an approach if you simply want a client to iterate across it (see my answer below)

Comment: Iterable is modifyable

Answer (score 4):

The `unmodifiableList()` method *should* have returned a new type that makes it obvious that it's unmodifiable. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77897) for a discussion about why this wasn't done.

As it is, you must make this limitation clear yourself. Usually it should be enough to mention this in the method's API documentation, particularly if it's obvious from the domain that inserting or deleting can't possibly work (nobody expects to be able to found a new country in the world just because `findCountries()` technically returns an Object with an `add()` method).

If your domain is not so clear-cut, it *can* be a good idea to make the limitation even clearer via the method name. For instance, if you have a `supportedFlavors()` method, it would not be totally unreasonable to believe that you can change the supported flavors by manipulating the list, and adding a warning via the name could be a better idea.

Comment: The unmodifiableList() returns a List, so I'm not sure what you mean - you said it should return a new type that makes it obvious that's it unmodifiable. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)

Comment: What he seems to mean is that unmodifiableList() should have returned a type for which the compiler ensured it is unmodifiable (by the type not having an add() method f.e.). This is not the case for the returned list as is, but is for instance the case for c#'s IEnumerable. I agree and the link elaborates, +1'd.

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing that the method simply returns a `List`, my first reaction was this:

> No, the method name should reflect what the method does in terms of
>   the problem domain. Nowadays, I can see no reason for adding type
>   information to method (or object) names. The return type should be
>   easily displayed by any decent IDE.
>
> This might have been different way back when people mostly read code
>   in a simple text editor or printed out on paper. In these times,
>   naming conventions like Hungarian Notation actually made sense.
>
> This also applies to the name of the returned object in the calling
>   function.

Now, having learned what `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)` actually does, I have to say, yes, make it *really* obvious in the method name *and* in the object name.

But most of all, I would try to avoid using this method at all. I would consider it very dangerous that the check is only performed at runtime.

Comment: The IDE will just show that the return value is a list, there's no way for it to show that the list is unmodifiable (since "unmodifiable list" isn't a data type).

Comment: @FrankPuffer - unfortunately, Java doesn't provide the option of performing the check at compile time, runtime is the only option.  Using the method is a better option than not, because failing quickly at runtime with an exception is better than obscure bugs occurring later because a collection that shouldn't have been modified has been.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I document this by returning `Collection<? extends ElementType>` instead of `Collection<ElementType>`.
That way adding elements is clearly unsupported. And remove being unsupported is thus implied.
You might make it more explicit if

- it is a public API
- source is not readily available to clients of the interface
- the domain is not obvious

Comment: +1 - this is a nice answer.  A bit of a hack, but it *will* make the compiler catch errors, rather than leaving them until runtime.

Comment: You can still add `null`- ok, probably not by accident. And the compiler won't provide any errors or warnings on calling `clear` etc.

Comment: @Hulk: If you really want to, you can still mess up. I only add it as a hint / documentation. If there is an explicit need to avoid changes to the result, you should use one of the `Collections.unmodifiableXXX` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> Should the method name indicate that it's returning an unmodifiable
>   list? That could prevent clients of my class from attempting to add or
>   remove objects from the list.

No. Your *interface* needs to enforce the read-only nature (and, as an aside, you need to decide if the object returned is immutable, or whether it can change whilst your clients are inspecting or holding it. i.e. is *defensive copying* a valid goal here?).

Comment: I think it can't be stressed enough. don't focus on how to punish developers for doing something wrong (by throwing exceptions and making them read obscure docs). focus on making the right thing the only thing you're physically able to do!

Comment: I like the idea of returning an Iterator, but often the user also needs to check the size of the Collection.  Wish there were an IteratorAndSize interface.  :-)

Comment: [Iterator.remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove())

Comment: I return a list that is unmodifiable by using Collections.unmdofiableList, is there anything wrong about it? Clients cant modify it, and even if they try to, an exception will be thrown. So my interface DOES enforce that the returned list is unmodifiable. Im asking if the method name should indicate it as well.

Comment: The runtime enforces this but the compiler doesn't. So someone can write code that will throw an exception when running. You really want the compiler to reject the code out of hand instead

Comment: So I need a new class to do it

Comment: +1 for @Basilevs comment, -1 to this answer.  Neither Collection (which contains the methods `add`, `addAll`, `clear`, `remove`, `removeAll` and `retainAll`) nor Iterator (which contains `remove`) will achieve the desired result of preventing modification.  The only thing they will do is prevent random access to the contents of the list, which there is no clear reason to do.  Unfortunately, Java has been designed specifically not to have interfaces or classes for read-only collections because the designers thought it would result in too large an API, so what you suggest is impossible.

Comment: @Jules - Yes, you're absolutely right re. Collection, which for some reason I'd thought didn't allow removal. Now amended. However I think the original intent of the answer is still perfectly valid